# Calculate the conditional median value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, median, array-formulas

I have the following values:

```
Type     Value    
A         5  
B         6  
A         3  
B         7  
A         9  
A        11
```

I want to calculate the median value for Type A, and ignore values for Type B.

How would I accomplish this, as there is no MEDIANIF function in Microsoft Excel?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(A:A="A",B:B))
```

entered CSE.

Comment: A great simplification